# PHP $_REQUEST not correctly working on link

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following link that is to update data in a mysql db

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#006600"><a href="update.php?ID='.$data["ID"].'&id='.$data["Product_sku"].'&name='.$data["Name"].'&retail='.$data["Suggested_Retail"].'&ounces='.$data["Item_Ounces"].'&upc='.$data["UPC"].' ">update</a></td>
```

But when it goes to the form it displays the php code in the fields

```
<form method="post" action="update_ac.php">
                        <table>         <tr><br /></tr>
                                <tr><td>  ID:  </td><td> <input type="text" name="ID" id="ID" value="<? echo $_REQUEST['ID']; ?>">* ID Number<br></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>  Product #:  </td><td> <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<? echo $_REQUEST['id']; ?>">* SKU<br></td></tr>
                                <tr><td> Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<? echo $_REQUEST['name']; ?>">* Product Name<br></td></tr>
                                <tr><td> Suggested Retail:</td><td> <input type="text" name="retail" id="retail" value="<? echo $_REQUEST['retail']; ?>">* Retail Cost?<br></td></tr>
                                <tr><td> Ounces: </td><td> <input type="text" name="ounces" id="ounces" value="<? echo $_REQUEST['ounces']; ?>">* Ounces <br></td></tr>
                                <tr><td> UPC: </td><td> <input type="text" name="upc" id="upc" value="<? echo $_REQUEST['upc']; ?>">* New UPC<br></td></tr>

                                <tr><td> </td><td align="left"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Data"></td></tr>
                        </table>
                </form>
```

So in the form fields it just says this instead of the information from the DB.

```
 <? echo $_REQUEST['name']; ?>
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: What error do you receive ?

Comment: Hey David, I know short tags make things shorter (hehe), but try to use full tags. Many, many, many servers do not support short tags by default and thus this code will be far less 'portable'. Simply changing out <? with <?php will save you, or future developers that work with your code, tons and tons of effort.

Answer (score 2):

You miss the php part of the opening tag: `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

The opening tag should be `<?php` and you use wrong quotes in the `href`.

```
"update.php?ID='.$data["ID"].'
```

Should be

```
"update.php?ID=".$data["ID"]."
```

(And all other occurences in the same string as well)

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct format.  This is what fixed my issues. I updated my server and that must have broke the short code i was using.

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['name']; ?>
```